# How to close modal dialog windows from javascript

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page from which modal dialog page gets opened. After page is opened, the user makes some selections and clicks on the button and some javascript gets executed. After it is done, I need to close the modal page. I tried `window.close()` but it did not work. How can I close the modal dialog page from javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
apex.navigation.dialog.close(true)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/javascript_api.htm#AEAPI30096

Answer (score 0):

I have rarely seen the documentation on the method below. I had to read a book to find out.

Try this:

redirect to URL:

```
javascript:closeModal();
```

You can also pass the modal parameter if necessary:

```
javascript:closeModal('P2_HELP_MODAL');
```

You can also open the same way:

```
javascript:openModal('P2_HELP_MODAL');
```